# How to hide/remove permanently Extensions view from Activity Bar in VSCode - OSS

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to remove "Extensions" from Activities Bar? Permanently from VSCode - OSS. I mean VSCode open-source variant: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Differences-between-the-repository-and-Visual-Studio-Code

I would like to use Code - OSS as an editor without the extension feature visible at all. (But still working underneath). I would like to also remove the Extensions shortcut - CtrL+Shift+X appearing in the context menu after right-clicking on VSCode - OSS. Activity Bar.

[image: View of Extension toggle I would like to remove also]

Comment: VSCodium is not VSCode in many aspects, so you should post to its own place and ask for assistance, https://github.com/VSCodium/vscodium/issues It's also improper to use VSCode specific tags, so answers to such questions won't help VSCode users.

Comment: Hi Lex. Thank you for pointing this out. I rephrase the question to match VSCode OSS as a generic VSCode Open Source variant.